# python mechanicalsoup redirection issue

Tags: redirect, mechanicalsoup

guys, actually I have a problem in my code and the redirection feature in my router, after I wrote the code which able to find the form and login into the router I faced a problem that after the login using the login.cgi the router redirects the link into something like http://192.168.1.2/index.asp;session_id=2dfa2490ad2e26a3d073edfdae7d0f45
what I could understand that it shows the session id in the link and I need help to make my code understands and gets the link I tried many times using 
browser.get_url() but it shows http://192.168.1.2/login.cgi

thank you guys

```
def wifi_pass_changer():
   username = 'admin'
   password = 'admin'
   url = "http://192.168.1.2/"
   browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
   browser.open(url)
   browser.select_form('form[action="login.cgi"]')
   browser["http_username"] = username
   browser["http_passwd"] = password
   response = browser.submit_selected()
```

Comment: Why no one help 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703203/mechanicalsoup-is-not-redirecting-to-where-it-should-redirect-to/50704100?noredirect=1#comment88418166_50704100