# mechanicalsoup is not redirecting to where it should redirect to

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to make a webscraping bot that logs into https://adelbert.magister.net/ so that I can scrap data in the website after logging in.

My code:

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
    soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
    raise_on_404=True,
    user_agent='bot',
)

browser.open("https://adelbert.magister.net/")
print(browser.get_url())
```

If you visit the page in your normal browser it redirects to a URL that looks like this: https://accounts.magister.net/account/login?sessionId=6aa0c7f9387a4b4b8acea413446d918c&returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DM6-adelbert.magister.net%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fadelbert.magister.net%252Foidc%252Fredirect_callback.html%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520magister.ecs.legacy%2520magister.mdv.broker.read%2520magister.dnn.roles.read%26state%3D505f79f6dc244b8ba45daaa215709ac0%26nonce%3D49d332e1fb2e499fb2a17bcd37d756a4%26acr_values%3Dtenant%253Aadelbert.magister.net#!/gebruikersnaam

How can I get it on the good page so that I can make the program login with mechanicalsoup?

This is the same question as posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893406/python-mechanicalsoup-redirection-issue) but no one has answered that post. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect is done using JavaScript. MechanicalSoup won't help with JavaScript (see MechanicalSoup's [FAQ](http://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails)).

Comment: Do you know a way to do it? Using a different library or so?

Comment: @C1rcu1tB04rd when JavaScript is involved, you need to use Selenium.